# Get tag and category posts WP SQL

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am a ios developer and have some problems with sql queries.

I get wordpress posts with query like:

```
SELECT id, post_title, post_content FROM `posts` 
WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post';
```

But I need to get some tag posts and category posts like:

```
SELECT id, post_title, post_content FROM `posts` WHERE category = '1';
```

and

```
SELECT id, post_title, post_content FROM `posts` WHERE tag = '1';
```

I got that tags and categories are in `terms` table. How can I connect two tables and get needed posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look in wp_terms table to get term_id for your tag, then look in wp_term_taxonomy table to convert to term_taxonomy_id. This can then be used to filter the wp_term_relationships table to get a list of post ids. Here is some SQL to get a list of post ids from either a tag or category name

```
SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id=wp_term_taxonomy.term_id 
WHERE name='tag,category'
```

To get actual posts you could use each object_id to filter wp_posts eg

```
SELECT ID,post_title,post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE ID='object_id'
```

or you could do it in one query to get all posts with specified tag,category

```
SELECT ID,post_title,post_content FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id=wp_posts.ID
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id=wp_term_taxonomy.term_id 
WHERE name='tag,category'
```

Comment: thank you for answer! one more question! can i get `posts` ID, title, post_content and tag_name by category? i need fourth column with tags...

Comment: Probably. Not sure offhand how that'd be done. You could do something similar to above given a post id to get a list of tags. SELECT name FROM wp_terms INNER JOIN .... WHERE ID='post id'. Checkout https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html and how JOIN works. You should be able to work it out from that.